# Select Choices not updating but AJAX call is working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've debugged my ajax call which is carried out by (and then recieves the data from the server) id_TableName and id_ColumnName are the names of my two select components on my html page;

```
function tableSelectionChanged()
        {
            var selected_table = $("#id_TableName option:selected").text();
            $.get('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', {selected_table : selected_table}, function(data){
            $("#id_ColumnName").val(data);
            });
        }
```

The data being returned by the server is in the following format;

```
(('option1', 'option1'),
('option2', 'option2'))
```

and so on...

I think there is a problem with the line;

```
$("#id_ColumnName").val(data);
```

where I try to fill the options of the select component with the options retunred from the server.

Comment: The returned data format is incorrect, and will cause errors. It is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan so what is the correct format?

Comment: That depends on how you want it to work. You could return HTML and simply set the `html` property of the select to the returned `data`. Or you could return JSON and build the HTML yourself from the deserialised object.

Comment: If I were to return html would I have to write the required html such as '<option value="option1"></option> /n <option value="option2"></option>' and so on?

Comment: and secondly, by building the html do you mean go in a loop and create the select options? if so could you get me started on the syntax for that in an answer?

Comment: see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
Put server side code    
    $strOption ="<option value=0 >Select All</option>";
            while($row =   mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
         $strOption.= "<option value='".$row['location']."' >".$row['location']."</option>";
        }
       echo $strOption;
```

client code 
        $('#cmbProject').change(function() {
                           $.post("callajx.php?drpname=Location", $("#DataAnalytics").serialize(),  function(response) {
$('#cmbLocation').find('option').remove().end().append(response).val('Select All');
                           });

Comment: i'm not using php, it's a python django web app

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you should use `html()` to set the options, the format you are returning the data is rather odd, and will cause you problems. You have two options.

Firstly, you could return HTML from your AJAX request (exactly how you do this will depend on your server side code)...

```
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
<option value="foobar">FooBar</option>
```

... and then set that directly as the `html()` property of the `select` element.

```
function tableSelectionChanged() {
    var selected_table = $("#id_TableName option:selected").text();
    $.get('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', { selected_table : selected_table }, function(data){
        $("#id_ColumnName").html(data);
    });
}
```

---

Option 2 is to return AJAX and build the HTML yourself. In this case the returned data would be smaller (and therefore quicker for the UI to retrieve), but would require more JS processing.

```
{
    "options": [{
        "foo": "Foo"
    }, {
        "bar": "Bar"
    }, {
        "foobar": "FooBar"
    }]
}
```

```js
function tableSelectionChanged() {
    var selected_table = $("#id_TableName option:selected").text();
    $.get('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', { selected_table : selected_table }, function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.options.length; i++) {
            for (var key in data.options[i]) {
                $('<option />', {
                    value: key,
                    text: data.options[i][key]
                }).appendTo('select');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Fs7G8/)

Comment: Thanks for that, in my firefox debugger I'm getting an error saying data.options is undefined.. i assume this is because of my format of return data?